# Drawer menu not closing

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I created a drawer menu using the DrawerNavigation feature of react-navigation. I wanted to create a button that would close the menu but the onPress function seems to not work

I've imported DrawerActions from 'react-navigation-drawer' and I've tried using different syntaxes

ex.) this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
     this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  
  Image, 
  StyleSheet, 
  Text, 
  ImageBackground, 
  TouchableWithoutFeedback, 
  View, 
  Button,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import { 
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator, 
  createAppContainer,
  DrawerItems,
  SafeAreaView,
  NavigationActions
   } from 'react-navigation';

import { DrawerActions, } from 'react-navigation-drawer';


const navigator = createDrawerNavigator(
{
  Home: Lander,
  Page1: Lander,
  Page2: Lander,
  Page3: Lander,
  Page4: Lander,
},


{
 contentComponent: (props) => (
     <SafeAreaView>
        <View style= {{backgroundColor:'black'}}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())}>
              <Image source={require('./Images/x.png')} style = {styles.cross}/>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View> 
        <ScrollView style= {{backgroundColor: 'black', paddingLeft: '5%'}}>
              <DrawerItems {...props} />
         </ScrollView>


   </SafeAreaView>

        )
    },






);
```

I ultimately want to be able to click on the x button and let it redirect me to the home screen.

I'm getting the following error

> Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')

Comment: Try checking with this : `this.props.navigation.closeDrawer()`

Comment: The same error occurs: "Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing `DrawerActions` from the wrong package.

Change

```
import { DrawerActions, } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
```

To

```
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation'
```

And to close it, you do it like

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}
```

## Edit:

What you are doing wrong is that you get `this.props` but it's only `props`.

```
contentComponent: (props) => (
     <SafeAreaView>
        <View style= {{backgroundColor:'black'}}>
            {//                           changed to props without this}
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())}>
              <Image source={require('./Images/x.png')} style = {styles.cross}/>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View> 
        <ScrollView style= {{backgroundColor: 'black', paddingLeft: '5%'}}>
              <DrawerItems {...props} />
         </ScrollView>
     </SafeAreaView>    
)
```

Comment: you are using `this.props.navigation` but it should be only `props.navigation`

Answer (score 0):

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(App));
```

hope is helps